# Big \sum instead of small \sum in array environment

Tags: symbols, equations, align

```
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c}
\min \: A = \min \: \sum_{i\in B} C_i 
\\ \\
\min \: D = \min \: \sum_{i\in B} \pi_i \cdot F_i
\end{array}
\end{align*}
```

[image: image of the equation]
How can I get `i \in B` below the `\sum` symbol without breaking the `align` into multiple aligns?

Comment: I strongly advise you to consider Hendrik's answer: the fact that \sum is typeset in textstyle is a signal that array is not the right environment to typeset your equations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By putting a `\displaystyle` in front of the `\sum`. You basically want the font to behave like it does in a top-level environment, because it's nested in an array it gets assigned a `\textstyle` font size.

Why you're not aligning the equations on the equals sign beats me though. It might be better to use two `equation` environments in this case, the code wouldn't look so bloated as it does now.

Comment: Thanks. I do not align them on the equal sign because in reality one is much larger than the other. Aligning them does not look very nice...

Comment: @Frank: Then you shouldn't be using `align`. You should take a look at the other math environments provided by `amsmath` and pick one that's more suited to what you're doing. Using `array` is wrong.

Comment: @TH: I only knew of equation and align. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Frank: There is a `gather` environment that does exactly what you want, i.e., combine multiple equations without aligning them.

Answer (score 11):

I would typeset this as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
\min \: A &= \min \: \sum_{i\in B} C_i \\
\min \: D &= \min \: \sum_{i\in B} \pi_i \cdot F_i
\end{align*}
```

Then it is aligned, and the sums are as you want them. If you do not want it aligned, use `gather` instead of `align`. If you want more vertical space between the two lines, use `\\[1ex]` instead of `\\`. (Incidentally, I would not use `\:` after the `\min`.)

Comment: "I would not use" is an understatement, the space  of course ought not to be there.