# Problem with \sum subscript

Tags: amsmath

When I use the code below the subscript `j` appears to the side of the sum symbol, not underneath. Has anyone got any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
\begin{equation}
    \Delta{t}\leq\left[{C_i}\over{{\sum_{j}}{\frac{1}{R_{ij}}}}\right]_{min}
    \label{eq:stability_criteria_3}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please put your code in Code Samples (the '{}'-button) to make it more readable

Comment: Here is the same issue in another environment. Solution is the same: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3262/big-sum-instead-of-small-sum-in-array-environment

Comment: In LaTeX, rather use `\frac{<num>}{<denom>}` than `<num>\over<denom>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using `\limits` as in the following:

```
    \begin{equation}
\Delta{t}\leq\left[{C_i}\over{{\sum \limits_{j}}{\frac{1}{R_{ij}}}}\right]_{min}
\label{eq:stability_criteria_3}
     \end{equation}
```

(Doesn't this make this ugly though?)

Answer (score 8):

Adding a `\displaystyle` does the job.

```
\begin{equation} \Delta{t}\leq\left[{C_i}\over{{\displaystyle \sum_{j}}{\frac{1}{R_{ij}}}}\right]_{min} \label{eq:stability_criteria_3} \end{equation}
```

Comment: The `\displaystyle` instruction will change both the size of the summation symbol and the default placement of the limit(s) of summation.