# Problems while displaying sum limits below

Tags: math-operators, mathtools

I'm having some trouble when trying to correctly display a summation using LaTeX.

I'm using the package `mathtools`, and the formula:

```
Cov(O) = \frac{ \sum_{\forall c_i \in C} exists(O, c_i)}{n}
```

My problem is the `\forall c_i \in C` text appears as a sub index of the `\sum` element instead of appearing below it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question seems very similar to [Problem with sum subscript](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64393/problem-with-sum-subscript). Can you check if the accepted solution works for you? In this case, please let us know by leaving a comment; otherwise, try being more precise in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is standard because the arguments of `\frac` are in textmode math. Try `\frac{\displaystyle ...` or `\frac{\sum\limits_{....`

BTW: One usually never write `\forall` in the limits of the sum, one would usually just write `\sum_{c_i \in C}`, the for all is implied

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer rewriting the text as follows:

```
\Cov(O) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{\forall c_i \in C} \texists(O, c_i)
```

It seems that `Cov(0) and`exists(0,c_i)` are functions, so it should be typeset as one. For that, add this to the document preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % not needed if it's already in the preamble
\DeclareMathOperator{\texists}{exists}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov}
```

Notice that we cannot use the name `\exists` since it already exists `;)`